# How can I get an input's value on a button click in a Stateless React Component?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following functional component

```
const input = props => (
  <div>
    <input placeholder="Type a message..." />
    <div onClick={props.send} className="icon">
      <i className="fa fa-play" />
    </div>
  </div>
)
```

How could I possibly pass the value of the input to `props.send()`?

Comment: you want input value in your parent component which has send() method. Right ?

Comment: Yeah, but only on the button click. I know I could define an onChange handler and update the value on every keystroke but I think that's not very performant, since the value is only sent when the button is clicked.

Comment: Is it necessary that your input component is a state-less component? Because in that case you can't use `ref`, which would require to use a bit unusual way of accessing the `input` value..

Comment: No, not necessary, but I am just trying to go by the React convention of maximizing the use of functional components. I figure this is a common use-case when working with inputs?

Comment: Would there be any downsides to using a Class, as opposed to a stateless component here? Kinda new to React.

Comment: @AamirKhan Remember there's no downsides If you use class or pass a changeHandler from parent component as long as your component is not keep re-rendering.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I found a solution for this exact scenario on React's official docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#refs-and-functional-components

This approach allows your component to remain stateless and also doesn't require you to update the parent component on every change.

Basically,

```
const input = props => {

let textInput = React.createRef();

function handleClick() {
  console.log(textInput.current.value);
}

return (
    <div>
      <input ref={textInput} placeholder="Type a message..." />
      <div onClick={handleClick} className="icon">
        <i className="fa fa-play" />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

---

Edit May 2021: Since this answer seems to be getting some attention, I have updated the answer to use a hooks based approach as well, since that is what I would use now (If using React 16.8 and above).

```
const input = props => {  
  const [textInput, setTextInput] = React.useState('');

  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log(textInput);
    props.send(textInput);
  }

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setTextInput(event.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={handleChange} placeholder="Type a message..." />
      <div onClick={handleClick} className="icon">
        <i className="fa fa-play" />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: You're a life-saver! So many answers online want you to make the component stateful or store the input data in the parent's state - but for my particular use case, your solution works best. Thanks.

Comment: @CaleSwitzer you can now use hooks as well. I would probably use that approach now.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it since you're very much concerned about performance. Here is the implementation, your component will be rendered only when you click on send button which actually means state will be updated once and input value will be displayed in parent component.

```
const Input = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={props.changeHandler} placeholder="Type a message..." />
      <button onClick={props.send}>send</button>
    </div>
  );
};

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    inputValue: ""
  };

  inputValue = '';

  send = () => {
    this.setState({ inputValue: this.inputValue });
  };

  changeHandler = event => {
    this.inputValue = event.target.value;
  };

  render() {
    console.log("In render");
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Input changeHandler={this.changeHandler} send={this.send} />
        <div> {this.state.inputValue}</div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned that you just started with React, I'd suggest that you work through the **[documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html)** (which offers nice explanation).

According to your comment, the usage of a functional component is not a requirement. Therefore I'd recommend to do it that way -->

Your `CustomInput` component:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class CustomInput extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.textInput = React.createRef();
  }

  static propTypes = {
    send: PropTypes.func
  };

  render() {
    const { send } = this.props;
    return (
      <React.Fragment> 
        <input placeholder="Type a message..." ref={this.textInput} />
        <div
          onClick={() => send(this.textInput.current.value)}
          className="icon"
        >
          CLICK ME
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default CustomInput;
```

If you noticed, I've replaced the empty `div` with `React.Fragment`. In that case you can omit the unnecessary `<div>` wrappings (if those are not required) which will keep your DOM clean (Read more about it **[here](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html)**.

Usage:

```
<CustomInput
   send={(prop) => {
      console.log(prop)
   }}
/>
```

I just used a dummy function which will log the input value to the console..

You can check the working example (Make sure to trigger the `console` in the editor) **[here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nkpy710wzp)**

Comment: He asked for a functional component.

Answer (score 0):

Posting this answer, If incase someone is using an earlier release of React 16.3. We can achieve the same thing by using `callback refs` instead without having to maintain state or having onChange event handler:

```
const input = props => (
  <div>
    <input ref={props.myRef} placeholder="Type a message..." />
    <div onClick={props.send} className="icon">
      <i className="fa fa-play" />
    </div>
  </div>
)
```

Calling that Input Component

```
handleClick = () => console.log(this.inputRef.value);

<Input myRef={el => this.inputRef = el} send={this.handleClick} />
```